# sql keeps stopping seemingly half way?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

When i run my program, the sql command gets to table.executenonquery and just stops, it loads the program interface and nothing else happens? I have viewed the database and it has not added the table i needed. Here is my code:

```
private void loginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = "DataSource=\"Event Control.sdf\"";
        SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
        en.CreateDatabase();
        string createTable = "CREATE TABLE Login (userName nvarchar(50), Salt nvarchar(100), Hash nvarchar(100)";
        string connection = "Data Source = Event Control.sdf";
        SqlCeConnection connexion = new SqlCeConnection(connection);
        SqlCeCommand table = new SqlCeCommand(createTable, connexion);
        try
        {
            connexion.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        table.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connexion.Close();
    }
```

It gets to the end (table.ExecuteNonQuery) and just stops. Dead. And FYI, Im not sure if its executenonquery or executescalar (not sure of the difference) but i have tried both

Thanks guys

Comment: why would you be creating the login table on form load?

Comment: because i cant seem to create a table and database and refer to them in my program, then publish it for use on other computers, the program wont find the database, so i figured i'd make the database when the user (whoever it is) first opened the program

Comment: "because i cant seem to create a table and database and refer to them in my program" - there's your problem!!! Treat the cause, NOT the symptoms. If your shoes don't fit, you don't cut off your toes.

Comment: no. I think you misunderstand. My program used to contain a database, but when i deployed it, it wouldnt find it and there were all sorts of issues with install folders and database locations, ive asked countless times and no-one has managed to help, so i thought i would create the database "on-site" when the user launched the program, it would automatically create the database in the program folder. So, why does it keep stopping at execute command?

Comment: it passes through the connection fine, it creates the database no problem, but when it reaches the second to last command it just stops and opens the form

Comment: so no one can help??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create statement fails because you are missing a closing paren

```
string createTable = "CREATE TABLE Login (userName nvarchar(50), Salt nvarchar(100), Hash nvarchar(100)"
```

should be

```
string createTable = "CREATE TABLE Login (userName nvarchar(50), Salt nvarchar(100), Hash nvarchar(100))"
```

Your application doesn't "just stop" it throws an exception with message of "{"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 82,Token in error = ) ]"}" telling you the *exact* problem.

Having said that, this will invariably fail the second time a user runs the app, when it tries to create a database file that already exists.

Comment: THANK YOU! I cant believe i missed that! And to think, someone who ran a group dedicated to this stuff didnt notice it and just ran his mouth off instead.... Thank You!!!!